# BeagleBone Black: Cannot execute binary on MicroSD

Tags: c++, linux, arm, beagleboneblack

I recently purchased a BeagleBone Black Revision C. To test my first program this is what I did:

1. I plugged an old spare MicroSD card into BeagleBone Black's MicroSD Slot.
2. Connected BeagleBone Black directly to my Ubuntu PC using a USB cable and powered it on.
3. Used SSH to connect directly with the BBB board.
4. Debian OS on BeagleBone shows the contents of the MicroSD inside the /media/xxx folder.
5. I used nano to create a "hello world" C++ program and saved it on the microSD and used the on-board g++ to compile/link it.
6. Compilation/linking created an **a.out** binary on the MicroSD.

**My Issue:**

1. When I try to run the binary using the command ./a.out from my SSH prompt I receive a *Permisison Denied message*.
2. I unsuccessfully tried to set the executable flag using chmod command.
3. But everything works when I save the program on the on-board storage, compile and link it, and run the binary from there.

Please assist, I am a complete novice. My first guess is that Debian OS on the BeagleBone Black doesn't allow execution of binaries stored outside the on-board eMMC, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Is the MicroSD card formatted with a FAT filesystem? Or does it get mounted with the noexec flag? Either way, this question is probably better suited to [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The MicroSD is formatted with FAT filesystem. May be that is why it doesn't honour the **chmod a+x** command. I used the command **mount** to check the noexec flag but could not find it.